# Передать List в качестве параметра

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

У меня есть SQL-запрос, который я выполняю относительно сущности, которая сконфигурирована, как сущность без ключа, т.е

`context.TestEntity.FromSql("SELECT * FROM Table where IN (Какой-то список)")`

В этом запросе есть IN. Я могу как-нибудь в этот IN засунуть список строк или INT'ов в качестве параметра, чтобы EF сам экранировал если в этом есть необходимость и т д?

Что-то гуглил и ничего не нашел, что создало у меня впечатление, что такой возможности нет=(

Comment: Это EF вы работаете с объектами, используйте lamda для фильтрации и получения данных это простейший способ. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888559/how-to-query-entity-framework-objects-where-select-is-a-list

Comment: Т.е. у вас sql-запрос там? Без использования Linq?

Comment: Если у вас там сырой sql, то можно использовать DbParameter, который все это сделает

Comment: С кодом было бы понятнее о чём речь

Comment: [Это не ответ на ваш вопрос?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/857983/6468198)

Answer (score 0):

Этого в явном виде нет в Entity Framework, и не может быть, так как не любая СУБД поддерживает "составные" параметры на уровне своего протокола. Но SQL Server, например, поддерживает: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

Пусть у нас есть таблица Users, в которой поле Id целочисленного типа.

Мы можем вот так создать свой табличный тип:

```
CREATE TYPE ListOfIntegersType AS TABLE (i int)
```

И выполнить запрос с его использованием так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.Server;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }        
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }        

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                @"Data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial catalog=Database;Integrated security=True;");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> PrepareSequence(
            IEnumerable<int> src
            )
        {
            foreach (int item in src)
            {
                var ret = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("x", SqlDbType.Int));
                ret.SetInt32(0, item);
                yield return ret;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyContext entities = new MyContext();

            var users = entities.Users.FromSqlRaw(
                "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id IN (SELECT * FROM @tvpID)",
                new object[] {
                    new SqlParameter("@tvpID", SqlDbType.Structured)
                    {
                        TypeName = "dbo.ListOfIntegersType",
                        Value = PrepareSequence(new int[] { 6, 1365})
                    }
                });            
        }
    }
}
```

Выглядит не очень элегантно. Однако, EF для того и создан, что можно не писать вручную SQL, а использовать Linq Expressions с автоматической генерацией запросов. Тогда все это хозяйство можно переписать вот так:

```
var users = entities.Users.Where((x) => new int[] { 1, 2}.Contains(x.Id));
```

Необходимости в параметрах вообще нет, все и так строго типизировано. И все отлично работает! (На SQL Server по крайней мере.) Генерируемый провайдером запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[DisplayName] AS [DisplayName] 
FROM (SELECT 
[Users].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Users].[DisplayName] AS [DisplayName] 
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Users]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Это да, но это будет работать, если я извлекаю запрос через ExecuteSqlCommand ?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Если код с ExecuteSqlCommand у вас под рукой, возьмите и проверьте. ExecuteSqlCommand не возвращает результат запроса, то есть она вообще к EF как таковому отношения не имеет. Это просто обертка для DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
 List<int> Identities = // список идентификаторов
    List<Employee> result = _dbContext.Employees.Where(i=>Identities.Any(a=>a.Id == i))ToList();
```